# Byte array to Int in Python 2.x using Standard Libraries

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am comfortable in Python 3.x and Bytearray to Decimal conversion using int.from bytes(). Could come up with the below conversion snippet. Is there a way to achieve the same functionality using Python 2 for positive and negative integers.

```
val = bytearray(b'\x8f\x0f\xfd\x02\xf4\x95s\x00\x00')
a = int.from_bytes(val, byteorder='big', signed=True)

# print(type(a), type(val), val, a)
# <class 'int'> <class 'bytearray'> bytearray(b'\x8f\x0f\xfd\x02\xf4\x95s\x00\x00') -2083330000000000000000
```

Need to use Python 2.7 standard libraries to convert byte array to Int.

```
Eg. bytearray(b'\x00')--> Expected Result: 0
bytearray(b'\xef\xbc\xa9\xe5w\xd6\xd0\x00\x00') --> Expected Result: -300000000000000000000
bytearray(b'\x10CV\x1a\x88)0\x00\x00') --> Expected Result: 300000000000000000000
```

Comment: You probably better use `pack` for this.

Comment: I'm actually already surprised that Python-3.x does this, since in Python-3.x, an `int` has arbitrary size.

Comment: Sure Willem. Will see the docs for it now. Bt will that handle signed bytearrays to int conversion, or only positive integers?

Comment: Before posting, consider copying <your question title> and pasting it into google search bar.

Comment: Yup it does perfectly. I m on Python 3.6.1 | Anaconda 4.4.0. When i try this snippet locally in my higher version of Python it works but in 2.7 it does not.

Comment: Ok, i wont lie that i did check Google before posting, but the one you lead me to seems like only accept " little endian byte order".

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It's a perfectly sensible thing to do—but it isn't clear what the intended use is. Arbitrary-length signed ints aren't exactly a common interchange format. When you do see them, they're often in fixed chunks of 4 bytes, not 1 byte—or they're in gmp export format, which `from_bytes` would require a wordsize and nails arguments to handle, at which point it might as well default to `size=4, nails=2` for export so it could just dump its internal format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in function in Python 2.7 to do the equivalent of `int.from_bytes` in 3.2+; that's why the method was added in the first place.

If you don't care about handling any cases other than big-endian signed ints, and care about readability more than performance (so you can extend it or maintain it yourself), the simplest solution is probably an explicit loop over the bytes.

---

For unsigned, this would be easy:

```
n = 0
for by in b:
    n = n * 256 + by
```

---

But to handle negative numbers, you need to do three things:

- Take off the sign bit from the highest byte. Since we only care about big-endian, this is the `0x80` bit on `b[0]`.
- That makes an empty bytearray a special case, so handle that specially.
- At the end, if the sign bit was set, 2's-complement the result.

So:

```
def int_from_bytes(b):
    '''Convert big-endian signed integer bytearray to int

    int_from_bytes(b) == int.from_bytes(b, 'big', signed=True)'''
    if not b: # special-case 0 to avoid b[0] raising
        return 0
    n = b[0] & 0x7f # skip sign bit
    for by in b[1:]:
        n = n * 256 + by
    if b[0] & 0x80: # if sign bit is set, 2's complement
        bits = 8*len(b)
        offset = 2**(bits-1)
        return n - offset
    else:
        return n
```

(This works on any iterable of ints. In Python 3, that includes both `bytes` and `bytearray`; in Python 2, it includes `bytearray` but not `str`.)

---

Testing your inputs in Python 3:

```
>>> for b in (bytearray(b'\x8f\x0f\xfd\x02\xf4\x95s\x00\x00'),
...           bytearray(b'\x00'),
...           bytearray(b'\xef\xbc\xa9\xe5w\xd6\xd0\x00\x00'),
...           bytearray(b'\x10CV\x1a\x88)0\x00\x00')):
...     print(int.from_bytes(b, 'big', signed=True), int_from_bytes(b))
-2083330000000000000000 -2083330000000000000000
0 0
-300000000000000000000 -300000000000000000000
300000000000000000000 300000000000000000000
```

And in Python 2:

```
>>> for b in (bytearray(b'\x8f\x0f\xfd\x02\xf4\x95s\x00\x00'),
...           bytearray(b'\x00'),
...           bytearray(b'\xef\xbc\xa9\xe5w\xd6\xd0\x00\x00'),
...           bytearray(b'\x10CV\x1a\x88)0\x00\x00')):
...     print int_from_bytes(b)
-2083330000000000000000
0
-300000000000000000000
300000000000000000000
```

---

If this is a bottleneck, there are almost surely faster ways to do this. Maybe via `gmpy2`, for example. In fact, even converting the bytes to a hex string and unhexlifying might be faster, even though it's more than twice the work, if you can find a way to move those main loops from Python to C. Or you could merge up the results of calling `struct.unpack_from` on 8 bytes at a time instead of handling each byte one by one. But this version should be easy to understand and maintain, and doesn't require anything outside the stdlib.

Comment: thanks a lottt.. :) Works smooth. Have modified the question title as well. @Moderators plz feel free to update it if it still seems to be misleading. Nice snippet by abarnert for ppl with similar requirements.

Comment: For the record, converting to hex and parsing is *much* faster; `int(binascii.hexlify(mybytes), 16)` is *really* fast (I've had cause to reinvent this before, and that solution was orders of magnitude faster than any other option).